# Trying to convert JSON objects to JavaScript to display, not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having trouble converting JSON into JavaScript objects to display in html. Nothing shows up when I run it and I'm not really sure where the error is taking place. Am I converting it incorrectly or am I displaying it incorrectly? I have my code listed below

HTML where everything is supposed to be listed:

```
<table id="stars">
  <tr>
                    
  </tr>
</table>
```

The JSON is super long but this is the format:

```
{
  "stars": [
      {
        "name": "Sun",
        "id": 1,
         .....
      }
  ],
  "planets": [ 
     {
        "name": "Mercury",
        "id": 1,
         .....
     }
  ],
  "moons": [  
     {
        "name": "Moon",
        "id": 1,
         .....
     }
  ]
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
var stars = [];
var planets = [];
var dwarfPlanets = [];
var moons = [];

/* Document JS */
/* ----------- */
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.header').height($(window).height()); 

$.getJSON("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/600c5ab8bca934583e40b908", function(data) { 

/* Create Objects from JSON */
/* ------------------------ */

/* Stars */
$.each(data.stars, function (j,i) { 
  var star = JSON.parse(i);
  stars.push(star);
  addRow("stars", star.name, star.image, star.desc);
}); 

/* Planets */
$.each(data.planets, function (j,i) { 
  var planet = JSON.parse(i);
  if(planet.id <= 8) {
    planets.push(planet);
  }
  else if(planet.id <= 13) {
    dwarfPlanets.push(planet);
  }
}); 

/* Moons */
$.each(data.moons, function (j,i) { 
  var moon = JSON.parse(i);
  moons.push(moon);
}); 


/* Add Objects to Display */
/* ---------------------- */

/* Stars */
stars.forEach(addStar);
function addStar(star) {
  addRow("stars", star.name, star.image, star.desc);
}

/* Planets */
planets.forEach(addPlanet);
function addPlanet(planet) {
  addRow("planets", planet.name, planet.image, planet.desc);
}

/* Dwarf Planets */
dwarfPlanets.forEach(addDwarfPlanet);
function addDwarfPlanet(planet) {
  addRow("dwarfplanets", planet.name, planet.image, planet.desc);
}

}); 
});



/* Add a row of HTML */
/* ----------------- */
function addRow(type, name, image, desc) {
$('#stars').append('<a href="StarView/starview.html"> <div class="objectrow"> <tr>' + 
'<td>' + '<img src="Images/' + image + '.png" width="100" height="100" align="left" class="objectimage">' + '</td>' + 
'<td> <p class="objecttitle">' + name + '</p> </td>' + 
 '<td> <p class="objectdesc">' + desc + '</p> </td>' + 
 '</tr> </div> </a>'); 
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the content of the JSON string into objects.

So I removed the `JSON.parse` sintaxt that you have in your code.

Something like this:

```js
var stars = [];
var planets = [];
var dwarfPlanets = [];
var moons = [];

/* Document JS */
/* ----------- */
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.header').height($(window).height());

  $.getJSON("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/600c5ab8bca934583e40b908", function(data) {

    /* Create Objects from JSON */
    /* ------------------------ */

    /* Stars */
    $.each(data.stars, function(j, i) {
      var star = i;
      stars.push(star);
      addRow("stars", star.name, star.image, star.desc);
    });

    /* Planets */
    $.each(data.planets, function(j, i) {
      var planet = i;
      if (planet.id <= 8) {
        planets.push(planet);
      } else if (planet.id <= 13) {
        dwarfPlanets.push(planet);
      }
    });

    /* Moons */
    $.each(data.moons, function(j, i) {
      var moon = i;
      moons.push(moon);
    });


    /* Add Objects to Display */
    /* ---------------------- */

    /* Stars */
    stars.forEach(addStar);

    function addStar(star) {
      addRow("stars", star.name, star.image, star.desc);
    }

    /* Planets */
    planets.forEach(addPlanet);

    function addPlanet(planet) {
      addRow("planets", planet.name, planet.image, planet.desc);
    }

    /* Dwarf Planets */
    dwarfPlanets.forEach(addDwarfPlanet);

    function addDwarfPlanet(planet) {
      addRow("dwarfplanets", planet.name, planet.image, planet.desc);
    }

  });
});



/* Add a row of HTML */
/* ----------------- */
function addRow(type, name, image, desc) {
  $('#stars').append('<a href="StarView/starview.html"> <div class="objectrow"> <tr>' +
    '<td>' + '<img src="Images/' + image + '.png" width="100" height="100" align="left" class="objectimage">' + '</td>' +
    '<td> <p class="objecttitle">' + name + '</p> </td>' +
    '<td> <p class="objectdesc">' + desc + '</p> </td>' +
    '</tr> </div> </a>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="stars">
  <tr>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. One question, what exactly is being stored in the array variables now? Is it just JavaScript objects? Thanks again!

Comment: @joerup2004 You're welcome. Yes, it's an object. See in this link: https://ibb.co/7RnjRjR